# Java controls(jcx file) in weblogic workshop 8.1  and weblogic 10.3.4(Jdeveloper)

Tags: java, weblogic, oracle11g, wli

We have "Java controls(.jcx file)" features in weblogic workshop 8.1, now I want to use same "Java controls" in weblogic 10.3.4 with jdeveloper, SOA 11g(in BPEL process).

Can anyone suggest how we can use this feature? Is there any alternative for this Java controls?

I am asking this because I have upgraded my application from (weblogic workshop 8.1)WLI to SOA(11g)weblogic10.3.4, BPEL(Human Task Workflow) with Jdeveloper11g.

Comment: Hello, Moderator flags are for reporting serious issues with the site. If you need an answer urgently, consider revising your question a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no compatibility between the controls architecture used in WebLogic Workshop 8.1 (what became Apache Beehive for a time) and the technology behind SOA Suite 11g. BPEL processes use PartnerLinks and adapters to integrate with external components, and can perform Java callouts at given points.

There's no way I'm aware of to convert an existing .jcx control though.

Comment: Thanks for update, I searched it but did not find, finally I am doing the same as you mentioned....